# Executing a program before System Shutdown

Tags: c#, windows, shutdown

I have a program I need to run before a system shutdown executes. This means, before any program gets terminated because of the shutdown, I need to execute said program, ideally via Process.Start().

Initially I tried executing said program in the Windows Shutdown Scripts, however that script is only executed after programs have already been terminated. I however need to terminate some running applications in the right order.

I have tried the event SystemEvents.SessionEnding and SessionEnded, but this event does not let you wait for more than 1-2 seconds, and the cancelling of the shutdown is not possible either.

I got up to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089259/shutdownblockreasoncreate-create-multiple-reasons-to-display-during-logoff-shu) where, in the WndProc event about shutdown I would execute a Process. I reach the Event, I reach the point where I can actually pause the shutdown process. However, when I try to actually call a process, I get the "0xC0000142" error. 
A search for this resulted in one option being that the user is incorrect, however I want to call this application with the user that is running the executing program. The other option was that the environment path was wrong. I set an environment path for the second option, but in my opinion, I shouldn't need to change anything for the first option, since I want to execute it with the current user.

A third possibility I thought about might be that at this state of the system shutdown, no new processes can be spawned.

What can I do to fix this and actually execute the program here? I seem to be out of ideas at this point.

**Clarification:**
The "cleanup" program needs to shut down programs in a given order. The programs to be shut down are our own, but Windows Forms (the only way I can see that can use a shutdown handler) cannot be used there.
Program A is the one that handles the OnShutdown. Program A, on Shutdown, will call Program B, which does the ordered closing of programs. Program B, in my solution (that includes Forms) cannot be launched and returns an error, as specified in paragraph 4. The only user interaction here would be a user pressing a power button leading to system shutdown, or a remotely executed "shutdown.exe" call.

Comment: Is it your own tool or a third-party software you want to execute? If its your own, you could create a handler that triggers on the close-event. In this case you would also have to let your tool run from the beginning. Im using a software where the user has to logout. In case of a shutdown the close-event triggers an automatic logout.

Comment: Also if you are on windows: WIN+R -> gpedit.msc -> Userconfig -> Scripts. Not programmatically but maybe useful.

Comment: The on-shutdown script does not work since it already closes all applications in a quasi random order before the script is being executed, which leads to problems that my code is intended to avoid.


For the first reply, I added a clarification to the post, I hope that clarification answers the issue. No User Interaction, but tool running from the beginning is what I planned. automatic logout is not the issue, I need to execute a different program in case the logout happens.

Comment: Rather than trying to launch a separate "cleanup program" you should probably be detecting the incipient shutdown in each of the applications independently, and having them shut *themselves* down in the proper order.  There is no restriction on what sorts of applications can do this detection, if you don't know how to do it for some of them that would be a separate question.

Comment: (By the way, I believe you are right in thinking that you may not be able to start new processes once the shutdown reaches a certain point, and that this is the cause of the 0xC0000142 error.)

Comment: As a possible alternative, it may be possible to configure the power button so that it runs your application rather than causing the system to shut down.  (I know there's an option to do that, but I'm not sure whether it is still supported.)  That wouldn't affect remote shutdowns, though, you'd have to give the administrators a different way to initiate the shutdown via your application.

Comment: @HarryJohnston the problem with the application itself knowing when to shut down is the only way I found out how to block shutting down and waiting for another app to shut down first is to use Windows Forms, something that I cannot use for that application. Any alternative to that?

Comment: Also, with the approach in the link I put in the post, no program shuts down unless the WndProc method returns.

Comment: You don't need Windows Forms to detect shutdown.  You should post that as a separate question - checking first to see if an existing question already provides the answer, of course.  But looking at *this* question again, I wonder why A tries to launch B in order to shut down the other programs?  It seems to me that if A shut down the other programs itself, you wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: B is not a program designed to run in the background during the entire time the machine is running, it's designed (not by me) to be run once, execute, stop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108414/discussion-between-private-meta-and-harry-johnston).